# Web Scraping Python HTML

Tags: python

I'm trying to get Python to print a specific keyword in an HTML document from a website as you can see in my HTML example there is a phrase called "thisisthephrase" I'd like Python to just Print that. I know there are questions like this already but I could really use help in setting up the scripts I've only been studying Python for 2 months now.

My Python code

```
import urllib.request

fp = urllib.request.urlopen("example.com")
mybytes = fp.read()

mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
fp.close()

print(mystr)
```

HTML Example

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">var FB_PUBLIC_LOAD_DATA_ = [null,[null,
[[1428116796,"Where is it?",null,0,[[335017290,null,1,null,[[4,299,
["thisisthephrase"]
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the `thisisthephrase` phrase? Do you mean `Where is it?`?

Comment: If the html document uses javascript to create some of the content, you cannot simply use `urlopen` to get the full page.

Comment: Keyuer Potdar Sorry I just realized I didn't put in the most important part the key phrase it's in there now I was in a rush to get this posted I apologise

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommend you take a look at [Beautiful Soup library](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It works perfectly for manipulating HTML and XML documents.

I would be glad to help you more if you update your question by indicating a specific content to extract from.